# R number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I've wrote a function that must create a matrix of rxk and fill it up with the formule given in the code.

```
mCreate<-function(r,k)
{
 result<-array(0,dim=c(r,k))
  for(R in 0:(r-1)) 
  {
    for(K in 0:(k-1))
     {
      result[R][K] = 5*R^K-2*K^R
      }
   }
   return(result)
}
```

When I try to test this, I always get "R number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". I don't see why, I've searched on google and I always get the information that it is because I've going outbounds.

Comment: `result[R][K]` should be `result[ R , K ]`. Disclaimer: I'm not sure if that is the only error.

Comment: Also note that R arrays are 1-indexed.  The first element is at index 1 - not index 0.  You should probably read some introductory R materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `outer` for this instead...

```
mCreate <- function( r , c ){
  r <- seq_len(r)
  c <- seq_len(c)
  m <- outer( r , c , FUN = function(x,y) 5*x^y-2*y^x )
  return( m )
}

mCreate( 4 , 4 )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    1   -1   -3
#[2,]    8   12   22   48
#[3,]   13   29   81  277
#[4,]   18   48  158  768

#  Sanity check:
mCreate( 1 , 1 )
#     [,1]
#[1,]    3

#  Safety check:
mCreate( 0 ,0 )
<0 x 0 matrix>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. What I don't get is, the FUN function those X Y parameters where does the function get those? Are that the R C interval?

Comment: @user1480139 yes those `x` and `y` arguments to the function get their values from `r` and `c` respectively (i.e. they are positionally matched).